# Can you report use of product copy/likeness in video games for compensation?

Tags: copyright, international, trademark, compensation

If a video game (created outside of the US) has an exact copy on a 3D model used from a large world-wide corporation's (based in US) product is there a way of:

1. Reporting the use of likeness/copy
2. Getting paid for such a report

If so, what is the proper or best way to achieve this and would legal representation need to be used to make a report?

Comment: Can you report it, sure, is there any legal obligation to pay you for that information, probably not. If you are wanting to say "I have information if you give me money" that may be extortion.

Comment: Even if it was an exact copy, how do you know it was not done with permission? Are you the copyright holder? Even if there was no permission, your wording (copying the "likeness") suggests a possibility of no infringement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reporting the use of likeness/copy

There is no central, worldwide method to "report" copyright and/or trademark infringements. Determine the nationality of the creator of the game and the location(s) from which it is distributed and then look at the copyright and/or trademark laws for that county(s) and see if there is the remote chance you may have a case. See [International copyright treaties - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_copyright_treaties).

> Getting paid for such a report

Good luck. Find a lawyer willing to take on an international copyright/trademark dispute. They will advise you to not blow the large amount of money it would take to litigate for the very small chance you would prevail and even smaller chance you would get a settlement.

Comment: How can you have a case if you are not the copyright owner?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the copyright owner of the original product would offer to pay people who report violations. I think I have heard of a few that will, but most won't. At least under US law, they have no obligation to make such payments unless they have offered to do so or contracted to do so.

You could write or email the owner, and say "I know of a site that seems to be copying one of your products. I will tell you about it for a payment." They might say yes, but I rather doubt it.